# What hardware makes this sound?

Tags: audio

As its title is "I.B.M." and this album was released in 1978, obviously it's some kind of ancient computer, but I'm really curiuos, what exactly this is:
http://youtu.be/5amEt8d6Qk0. Is it the IBM MT/ST as said in the description?

Comment: That is a mix of sounds, possibly including some data transfer, but that isn't the predominant sound. The sound is filtered and processed but the main sound is a dot matrix printer, either operating at high speed or the sound has been sped up. What it is printing may have been specially prepared to produce those sound patterns.

Answer (score 1):

This sound like a phone line dial-up modem. Like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHW1ho8L7V8)

Comment: Not really IMHO

Comment: Think about 300 baud/s modem, the sound in my link is probably 9600 or more

Comment: Not like them too. Example: http://youtu.be/3I2Q5-15Mic

Comment: OK, is sound like mix of computer sounds, but for me the dominant is modem. Maybe mix with some computer sounds for pressed keys on keyboard

Comment: It does sound like a modem, but doesn't really seem to include the initial handshake.  Seems more like the sound you hear after a link is established, (and the modem speakers are normally muted).

Comment: Yes, when it is actually data transferred :)

Comment: You guys are old enough to remember modem sounds but don't recognize the sound of a high-speed dot matrix printer?